# Building a WAR project with unzipped JAR dependency?

Tags: maven-2, build-process

I have two projects, `my-lib` and `my-webapp`. The first project is a dependency of `my-webapp`. Thus, when ask Maven2 to build my WAR, the `my-lib` JAR is added in the `WEB-INF/lib/` directory of the web application.

However, I want to have the `my-lib` JAR unzipped directly in the `WEB-INF/classes` directory, exactly as if the `my-lib` sources were contained in the project `my-webapp`.

In others words, instead of having the following WAR content:

```
my-webapp/
  ...
  WEB-INF/
    lib/
      my-lib-1.0.jar
      ... (others third libraries)
```

I want to have that:

```
my-webapp/
  ...
  WEB-INF/
    classes/
      my-lib files
    lib/
      ... (others third libraries)
```

Is there a way to configure the `my-webapp` or the Maven2 war plugin to achieve that?

Answer (score 7):

As blaufish's answer says, you can use the maven-dependency-plugin's [unpack mojo](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html) to unpack an artifact. However to avoid the jar appearing in WEB-INF/lib, you need to *not specify it as a dependency*, and instead configure the plugin to [unpack specific artifacts](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html).

The following configuration will unpack the contents of some.group.id:my-lib:1.0:jar into target/classes during the process-resources phase, even if the artifact is not defined as a dependency. Be careful when doing this though as there is potential to clobber your actual content, this can cause much debugging.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>unpack-my-lib</id>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>unpack</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <artifactItems>
          <artifactItem>
            <groupId>some.group.id</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <overWrite>false</overWrite>
          </artifactItem>
        </artifactItems>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: plus it is better to add my-lib among regular dependencies in `provided` scope; if your war has classes that compile against this, it is a must. And, remove the version from the `artifactItem`, as it will be taken from the dependency.

Comment: Setting my-lib scope to provided excludes transitive deps for me with maven 3.0.4. Question now is how to use my-lib for compilation while adding only extracted contents AND transitive dependencies to the war.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the maven-dependency-plugin to just do that, unpack instead of copying a jar as explained [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html).

```
<project>
[...]
<build>
 <plugins>
   <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.5.1</version>
     <executions>
       <execution>
         <id>unpack</id>
         <phase>package</phase>
         <goals>
           <goal>unpack</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
           <artifactItems>
             <artifactItem>
               <groupId>junit</groupId>
               <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
               <version>3.8.1</version>
               <type>jar</type>
               <overWrite>false</overWrite>
               <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/alternateLocation</outputDirectory>
               <destFileName>optional-new-name.jar</destFileName>
               <includes>**/*.class,**/*.xml</includes>
               <excludes>**/*test.class</excludes>
             </artifactItem>
           </artifactItems>
           <includes>**/*.java</includes>
           <excludes>**/*.properties</excludes>
                 <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/wars</outputDirectory>
           <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
           <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
         </configuration>
       </execution>
     </executions>
   </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
[...]
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [unpack](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html) mojo seems to be close to what you are aiming for. Not sure how to complete the entire flow you are proposing though.

(btw, I am doubtful if this a good idea. utility classes should go into jars, and the jars are put either in the WAR or io the EAR. Unpacking utility jars seems wrong)

Comment: Concerning your comment: I only want to unpack *my* library, not the others ones. I want to do that because of the properties files, that may be modified. For the moment, these files are stored in the my-lib.JAR file, and if you want to modify one of the file, you need to unzip the JAR, modify the file and then repack the JAR...

Comment: Couldn't you just lay a patch into the classes directory when you modify a file?

Comment: Using this plugin, I've succeed to unpack the JAR in the WEB-INF/classes directory. However, I also have the my-lib.JAR in the WEB-INF/lib/ directory...

Answer (score 1):

[Oops, just realized that you were using Maven.  I don't delete this answer because it may come to the rescue of some Ant user.  So there's no need to mod me down...]

How many times to I have to mention that `Jar`, `War` and `Ear` Ant tasks are subtasks of the [Zip](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html) one? :-)  If I remember correctly, something like this would do the trick:

```
<war dist="my-webapp.war">
    <zipgroupfileset dir="libs" includes="*.jar" prefix="WEB-INF/classes"/>
</war>
```

Also worth a trial is with `src="mylib.jar"` but I haven't tested this option.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use the unpack mojo as described above, plus I marked the dependency itself as ["provided" (scope)](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) to avoid duplicating the jar contents under WEB-INF/lib.