# How do I use exploded jar dependencies?

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I've made a spring web application. It works with the jars in the lib folder but i need some of them unpacked. I know unpacking isn't the best way of doing things but I need it unpacked.

I created the jars myself. I need to be able to access module specific property files. Also before you ask, I've already looked at putting them externally and moving them to the war folder but both methods were not useable in this case due to some functionality. I'm working with an old badly made program. So my options are limited.

I'm trying to make some of my dependencies exploded. I've managed to explode a jar and put it in the 'WEB-INF\classes\< modulename>' in my deployed war using:

```
<plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>unpack</id>
              <phase>process-resources</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                  <artifactItem>
                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                    <type>jar</type>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/module1</outputDirectory>
                    <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                  </artifactItem>
                  <artifactItem>
                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                    <type>jar</type>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/module2</outputDirectory>
                    <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                  </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I've set the original dependency to provided scope as noted in this post:

[Building a WAR project with unzipped JAR dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368088/building-a-war-project-with-unzipped-jar-dependency)

However it doesn't seem to recognize the exploded folders. So what am i forgetting here? Do they have to be located somewhere else? Or do i need to put some reference to the new folders?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I've asked the moderator to delete this topic. Since i've solved it using the above topic. And since there hasn't been an answer to the question yet.

Comment: Why would you explode jars? What's the point? Also, do you realize that directory structure under WEB-INF/classes must match with the package structure for the class loader to be able to load classes?

Comment: I need them unpacked to be able to access certain files which i can't put anywhere else. I usualy have everything tucked away in Jars in my lib folder but this time i need them unpacked. So how do i use unpacked jars?

Comment: Also, when you say scope is *provided*, you're saying that the dependency can be found in the deployed environment (app server provides it) so you would not include the dependency in your deployment (e.g., war or ear)--so you don't need to include it as either an exploded jar or a regular jar if the dependency is provided.

Comment: Anything that is in a jar of WEB-INF/lib is accessible using the ClassLoader (ClassLoader.getResource[AsStream]), in exctly the same way as if it was in WEB-INF/classes. There is no need to unpack them.

Comment: I need to manualy edit the content of the files. Accessing them in the code isn't a problem. The program is working with the jars packaged. I just need them unpacked (and keep working).

Comment: @user2317875 I was following this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368088/building-a-war-project-with-unzipped-jar-dependency

Where they state that it is best to make the dependency provided scoped.

Comment: Highly recommend to keep things as simple as possible when configuring a Maven build--maybe you'll have more patience with it than I do however. I think this is usage of *provided* scope is unusual and I personally avoid like the plague doing anything unusual with Mavem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't extract the contents of the jar files.  There's no need to do that.  They're package up into jar files for a reason.  Place your jar files in the lib directory under the WEB-INF directory.  Tomcat will discover their contents on its own.

```
MyWebApp
    |
    |_ WEB-INF
         |
         |_ lib
              |
              |_ commons_1.0.jar
              |_ email_1.3.jar
```

Comment: I know, the application was running with the jar files. But i need some of them unpacked.

Comment: The jar files you are referring to, did you create them yourself, or did someone else create them?  What's in the jar file you need access to? Can't you refer to what you need in your code by first creating an import statement then making instances of the necessary classes?

Comment: I created the jars myself. I need to be able to access module specific property files. Also before you ask, I've already looked at putting them externally and moving them to the war folder but both methods were not useable in this case. I'm working with an old badly made program. So my options are limited. So i need my jar to be exploded so i can access the property files.

In the module are a few beans and classes that need to be picked up by spring's component scanner.