# Order of resource loading in WAR

Tags: java, maven, war

I have a Java webapp (WAR) that has several dependencies. Two of them contain resources to be exposed in the war (with the same name).

So my dependency tree looks like

[image: dependency tree]

The my issue is that the custom.css from the core.jar dependency is used if I access index.html

Is there a way to force the usage of the custom.css? I cannot modify core.jar

Thanks,
michael

Environment: Maven 3, Java 1.8, Tomcat 8

Answer (score 1):

There's no guarantee as to the relative ordering of JAR files in `WEB-INF/lib`, but it *is* guaranteed that `WEB-INF/classes` will be ahead of all the `WEB-INF/lib/*.jar` files in the classpath.  So if you can get the right `custom.css` into `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/resources` in your final WAR file it will be used in preference to the ones in the lib JARs by `ClassLoader.getResource`.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract and put necessary resources into myWAR itself.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's loaded by classloader (which is likely in your case) you're guarantied to not be able to force ordering.

You might be able to unpack the `core.jar` dependency and exclude the `custom.css` file as for example specified in [Building a WAR project with unzipped JAR dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368088/building-a-war-project-with-unzipped-jar-dependency)

In such case, you would exclude the `core.jar` dependency in `maven-war-plugin` (see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html) and configure `maven-dependency-plugin` to unpack `core.jar` to `target/classes` while excluding `META-INF/resources/custom.css`.